# What can be reason for no plugin-strings available under stable section on translate.wordpress.org?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, localization

I cannot see any plugin-strings under the stable section on translate.wordpress.org. What can be reasons for that?

P.S.: Under development section, I can see all the plugin-strings.

Comment: There can be lots of reasons - Can you post the plugin or Glotpress link?